# Derivative of capital Pi product

Tags: calculus, derivatives, products

I wanted to find the derivative of this function at $x=6$

$$y= \prod_{i=1}^{10} (x-i) = (x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-10) $$

without expanding all of the brackets, so I used the product rule to find a pattern. However, the resulting sum tells me that the derivative is zero at every whole number which is obviously not true. I've been over my solution and I can't see how I've gone wrong. Please could someone highlight where I went wrong? Thank you in advance.

\begin{align*}
      \frac{\textit{d}y}{dx} &= (x-2)(x-3) \cdots (x-10) + (x-1) \frac{d}{dx} \biggl((x-2) \cdots (x-10) \biggr) \\
       &= \prod_{i=2}^{10} (x-i) +  (x-1) \frac{d}{dx} \biggl(\prod_{i=2}^{10} (x-i) \biggr) \\
       &= \prod_{i=2}^{10} (x-i) +  (x-1)\prod_{i=3}^{10} (x-i) + (x-1)(x-2)\frac{d}{dx} \biggl(\prod_{i=3}^{10} (x-i) \biggr) \\
                &= \prod_{i=2}^{10} (x-i) +  (x-1)\prod_{i=3}^{10} (x-i) + (x-1)(x-2)\biggl(\prod_{i=4}^{10} (x-i) \biggr) + \cdots \\
                      &= \frac{y}{x-1} + \frac{y}{x-2} + \frac{y}{x-3}+\cdots + \frac{y}{x-10} \\
                             &= \sum_{i=1}^{10} \biggl(\frac{y}{x-i}\biggr)
    \end{align*}

Comment: That looks good.  What makes you think it is wrong?  It is not true that this vanishes at every whole number.

Comment: Man when I put x=6, y=0 because it contains (x-6) within it. So every term in my series at the end is zero so the derivate is zero when it should be 2880.

Comment: Oh, you are not cancelling terms.  If you do it carelessly then at $x\in \{1,\cdots, 10\}$ you get $\frac 00$ as one of the summands.  Clearly, however you mean to cancel out the common factors of $x-6$ from that term (or $x-i$ more generally, if $i$ is a root).

Comment: For instance;  try it at $6.0001$  for which the cancelling should be automatic.

Comment: Oh damn how could I be so careless.... thank you for pointing it out man I appreciate it

Comment: No worries, glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

A good strategy for derivatives of products is the logarithmic derivative:
If $f(x)=\prod f_k(x)$ then $\ln f(x)=\sum \ln f_k(x)$ and by taking derivatives on both sides
$$\frac {f’}f =\sum \frac {f_k’}{f_k}$$
Strictly speaking, we need all $f_k(x)>0$, but using the product rule, you can show that $f(x)\ne 0$ is sufficient.

In your example, this takes you very far.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is simpler to understand than this. In general suppose $f(x) = (x - a) g(x)$ and we want to compute $f'(a)$. (Here $g(x)$ could be a polynomial or more generally any differentiable function.) Then

$$f'(x) = g(x) + (x - a) g'(x)$$

which gives $\boxed{ f'(a) = g(a) }$. This is particularly easy if you notice that applying the definition of the derivative in this case directly gives

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = g(a).$$

Answer (score 0):

$y' = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10} \frac {y}{x-i}$ is a fine way to express your derivative for all those values of $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ in which case $y'$ is undefined.

However, $\lim_\limits{x\to n} \sum_\limits{i=1}^{10} \frac {y}{x-i}$ with $n$ in the subset of the natural numbers above, does exist, and equals $y'(n)$